# PSQLException: ERROR: could not open file - Operation not permitted

Tags: postgresql

```
14:57:24,484 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (bus [5]) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42501
14:57:24,484 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (bus [5]) ERROR: could not open file "pg_tblspc/16397/PG_11_201809181/10119411/4698976": Operation not permitted
  Where: parallel worker

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not open file "pg_tblspc/16397/PG_11_201809181/10119411/4698976": Operation not permitted
  Where: parallel worker
```

Tell me what is this error?

Comment: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not open file "pg_tblspc/16397/PG_11_201809181/10119411/4698976": Operation not permitted
  Where: parallel worker

Comment: Does the file exist? Does it belong to the PostgreSQL user?

Comment: Yes, it exists, and is owned by the postgres user, I wonder when restarting it - there was no problem.
Is it possible that the file was being occupied by some other process?

Comment: The most likely candidate would be an anti-virus program, particularly when you are on Windows. Those should never be allowed to touch the data directory.

Comment: Thanks, the anti-virus is installed on the hosts, perhaps the problem is in it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely candidate would be an anti-virus program, particularly when you are on Windows. Those should never be allowed to touch the data directory.